# Technical clarification on BSS model

Tags: complexity-theory

In BSS model in which one is allowed $\{+,-,\times\}$ operations, how is division and square root handled? Is there a typical procedure dealing with these involved situations?

Comment: Since Wikipedia does not seem to know the term, what is the BSS model in complexity theory? (Remember what you likely learned in your computability course: plus, minus and suitable forms of recursion/iteration are already Turing complete, so just build your other operations from these.)

Comment: @Raphael [Blum–Shub–Smale machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum%E2%80%93Shub%E2%80%93Smale_machine).